# react-native, XCode, <OneSignalFramework/OneSignalFramework.h> not found

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

Ошибка RCTOneSignalExtensionService <OneSignalFramework/OneSignalFramework.h> not found. (react-native, XCode, cocoapods)
На андроид версии все работает. Пробовал по двум инструкциям: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/react-native-sdk-setup, https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ios-sdk-setup.

Так же такое же приложение делал на swift и подключал по этой инструкции https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ios-sdk-setup, все работало. А вот с react-native не работает.

Пробовал заменить OneSignalFramework на OneSignal, OneSignalExtension - не помогло. Когда пишу #import <OneSignalFramework/OneSignalFramework.h> или что-то из этого, ругается что нет таких файлов

Пробовал различные варианты pod install (и с bundle, и c repo update). Уже незнаю что можно еще попробовать, в последний раз поудалял DerivedData, также сделал deintegrate. Вообщем там сейчас уже другие ошибки, но это другая история.

Comment: Так же заметил что в папке с проектом таких файлов как OneSignalFramework.h вообще нет

Answer (score 0):

решил проблему, правда не понял как.

как и описал выше, сделал все это, затем пошли другие ошибки, решение которых нашел [тут](https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/123790). после этого заработало.

Но полное решение я так и не запомнил, и в следующий раз придется заново проходить этот круг.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)